# Converting a returned array from an async function to a regular array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, asynchronous

It's been a while since I've written absolutely any code at all so I'm a little rusty. I've recently started writing a bot and am currently stuck on converting an array within an async function to a regular array to be parsed within another function.

```
    Private Async Function getmsgs(ByVal num As Integer) As Task(Of Array)
        Dim msgids As Array = Nothing
        Try
            Dim msg = Await Libx.DownloadMessages(num)
'starting loop to pull each message and assign to array
            For i As Integer = msg.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If (msg(i).Id > 0) Then
                    msgids(i) = msg(i).Id
                End If
            Next
'returning array
            Return msgids
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return msgids
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Sub deletemsgs(ByVal ids As Array)
        If Not ids(0) = Nothing Then
'incase library failed to retrieve messages
            Try
                For i As Integer = ids.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
'function called per item in array
                    libx.DeleteMessages(ids(i))
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

The issue occurs when trying to call `deletemsgs(getmsgs(argint))`.
I'm getting the error message
`Value of type 'Task(Of Array)' cannot be converted to 'Array'`

I've searched through a few forums with every relating search term I can think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers in advance.

Comment: `deletemsgs(Await getmsgs(1))` would probably fix your issue.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. Thanks very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `await` `async` functions.

An example being:

```
Dim arr As Array() = await getmsgs(1)
```

This will need to be inside of an `async` function for it to work correctly.

Comment: Wouldn't this eventually just keep travelling to each sub i wanted to use the function for though?

Comment: @riptonline: Yes. This "growth" of `Async` is natural and expected.

Comment: I figured out i'd needed to have async in just about every sub if i didn't tidy up one thing so was a little confused. Thank you :)